# is there any way to use variables like {{ ct{{ forloop.counter }} }} in HTML File in django?

Tags: python, html, django

views.py:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    params[f"ct{i}"] = '<h1>ct'+i+ '</h1>'
```

index.html:

```
<h1>{{ct{{forloop.counter}} }}</h1>
```

Is there any way to use `<h1>{{ct{{forloop.counter}} }}</h1>` in My HTML File?

Comment: What result are you exactly expecting?

Comment: why not keep it as normal list `data[i] = '<h1>ct'+i+'</h1>'` (or rather `data.append( '<h1>ct'+i+'</h1>' )` and send this list `params["ct"] = data` and later use normal list `{{ct[i]}}` or even iterate it `{% for item in ct %}<h1>{{item}}</h1>{% endif %}`